# React - проблема с хуками

Tags: javascript, reactjs, объекты, redux, jsx

При использовании пакета **npm "use-dark-mode"** я пытаюсь применить хук const `darkMode = useDarkMode (false);` внутри функции, но я получаю сообщение об ошибке

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Прежде чем предоставить вам код, я хочу объяснить более подробно, я думаю вы уже поняли из названия пакета что я хочу использовать темный режим в своем проекте, у меня много компонентов, я передаю значение темного режима через props, и он отлично работает за исключением одного компонента с именем **JavaScriptLessonObject**, затем я использую **react-html-parse**, я пытаюсь вызвать **useDarkMode** внутри этой функции, но здесь возникает ошибка, я уверен в том, что проблема заключается в том, что я вместо jsx пытаюсь вернут массив но что делать тогда в таком случае?

```
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode'

function JavaScriptLessonObject() {
    const darkMode = useDarkMode(false)
    return (
        [
            {
                title: [<p className={jsStyle.title}>Overview</p>],
            },

            {
                titleName: "Indorction",
                heading: 'What is JavaScript ?',
                iconName: faDotCircle,
                data: {
                    description: `              
                    <p class="con"> JavaScript is a dynamic computer programming language.
                    It is lightweight and most commonly
                    It is an interpreted programming language with object-oriented capabilities.</p>              
                    `
                },
            },
        ]
    );
}

export default JavaScriptLessonObject;
```

Comment: тебе же там пишут `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`! "Хук может быть вызван только внутри функциональной компоненты"

Comment: Разве мой компонент не является функциональным? Кроме этого я хук применил внутри функции, если сделал что-то не так будь добр продемонстрируй пример правильного кода в моем примере

Comment: Ваша "функциональная компонента" возвращает не jsx, а нечто другое, то-есть это не функциональная компонента

Comment: Как тогда в таком случае применить хук? Мне нужно всего брать значение из этого хука чтобы изменить цвет текста, может у вас есть идеи?

Comment: сбросьте код где используется JavaScriptLessonObject